# Mesh ground advantage over single rod ground

Tags: grounding, ground-plane

In high voltage laboratories, how do mesh grounds perform better than that of single rods?

Does frequency play a role here ?

Which one is more beneficial, using multiple single rods in lab for grounding or laying a mesh?

Comment: There's little better than a Ufer ground. And if there is a concrete floor, this means a whole lot of rebar criss-crossing throughout the floor concrete to form the ground. Dr. Ufer performed all the hard work and study results back around WW II. Pretty solid, but it has been verified multiple times through studies done in California in the late 1960's and 1970's. Probably many others. I don't know the particulars of high voltage laboratories. But I did work at one such place with a huge x-ray machine, when turned on, elevated the local ground voltage by over 7kV for a 100 yrds around it.

Comment: What was the output voltage of X-Ray Machine ?

Comment: It was a physics research system, the year there was 1982, and I never asked that question. I was instead dealing with the required optical fiber communications between buildings and measuring the problem before considering solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When lightning strikes, current flows through the physical earth. This results in different locations in the physical earth having different potentials. If there are multiple electrical connections to the physical earth, then at the moment of a nearby lightning strike, these electrical connections can be at different potentials. If equipment is connected to the multiple electrical connections to physical earth, a nearby lightning strike may result in current which is flowing through the physical earth, entering the building from the ground, passing through some equipment (or even people -- yikes!), and then returning to the ground (in another place).

For a small structure, the danger of the above scenario can be minimized by having a single point of electrical connection between the physical earth and the mains "ground" wire. However, even in small structures, the situation is complicated by the presence of electrically conductive pipes.

Larger structures generally have multiple lightning rods at their highest points. To be effective, lightning rods must be bonded to a wire that connects to a grounding rod, and the route of that wire needs to be as direct as possible (to minimize impedance). Thus, on a large structure, there will inevitably be many electrical connections to the physical earth. Further, the manufacturers of some large machines specify that the machine be provided with its own grounding rod. In a large structure it becomes increasingly difficult to isolate the mains grounding wire from the multiple connections to physical earth. Consequently the chances of a nearby lightning strike causing current to flow within the building grounding system increases.

Bonding together all of the physical connections to the earth by the most direct paths will hopefully create electrical paths between physical earth potentials that are of lower impedance than any path flowing through the mains wiring in the structure. In the US, all outside grounding rods are required to be bonded together,  near the earth surface, and this is usually done with a bare wire outside building, or a conductor embedded in concrete.

If the building is small enough, this bonding is often only around the perimeter of the building. However, if the building is large enough, the extra impedance involved in wiring *around* the building, and not also along the shortest paths between grounding rods becomes an issue.

Mesh grounds are the logical choice when it is impractical to ensure that there is only a single electrical connection to the physical earth, and some of the electrical connections to physical earth are a significant distance from each other. A mesh connecting all the electrical connections to physical earth will hopefully provide a low impedance path for current to flow, allowing that current to be diverted from conductors which expose equipment (and people) to harm from electric shock.